# bootstrap & CSS alignment in web application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using twitter bootstrap v3.  I have added the following within a navigation bar with the intention of moving the "Test" String all the way to the left of any screen size.  However, that does not happen (the text appears somewhere in between center and all the way to the left).  I have tried setting margin-left, passing-left & float options but I have not been successful.  Is there a specific setting I need to override in my css file (that overrides that in bootstrap) or perhaps use a different bootstrap rule for this purpose?
Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
 <a class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="#">Test</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-brand {
    margin-left:0px;
    float:none;
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

**Update:**

http://jsfiddle.net/haider14/BQVk3/

Please note that when you stretch the size of the window, the items do not pull-left or right all the way.

Comment: it would be great if you create a fiddle with more code... its hard to figure out the issue from provided description...

Comment: I would start off by looking at the developer tools in your web-browser (F12), both Mozilla and Chrome have tools that show the CSS rules being applied to an element, and the computed result.  It's a nice interface to figure out where you are inheriting from as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/haider14/BQVk3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because the container div has

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
width: 750px; }
```

you have to overwrite this somehow

```
.container {
 width: 100%; }
```

updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQVk3/4/)

Comment: thank you - both answers so far are correct.  I have to accept the first one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is a viable option for you, but instead of using fixed widths you can change `<div class="container">` to `<div class="container-fluid">`

http://jsfiddle.net/BQVk3/5/

Comment: thank you - both answers so far are correct.  I have to accept the first one.

Comment: Just a note, using `container-fluid` is pretty much the same as the other answer, but, you're not making unnecessary overrides to the base code that could trip you up later. In bootstrap `container` uses fixed widths `container-fluid` uses fluid widths, essentially giving you width: 100%